# How to send a session to another ASP.NET WebForm page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I have created an ASP.NET WebForm application. Let's say for example I have a string value and want to send it to another page in my app e.g.

```
string sValue = "information";
```

I then put this into a session as so:

```
Session["value"] = sValue;
```

I then want to navigate to another page in my web app so i use:

```
Response.Redirect("~/ViewInvoices.aspx");
```

However when I try to extract any information from the session it is null

```
string sValue = Session["value"]; <-is now null
```

Could anyone either spot the problem or even better offer a solution to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for redirecting:

```
Response.Redirect("~/ViewInvoices.aspx", false);
```

Comment: The Session["value"] contains null when i try to access it from the new page. (I should have added ".ToString()" to my example - i'll update it)

Comment: Throws a null exception error, i think it could be the way that i am navigating to another page that could be creating a new user session?

Comment: @BrianPeach your way for redirecting don't have any problem

Comment: After digging into it, the sessions are there as there is a count however they are all set to null :S

Comment: @BrianPeach you are right, change your redirect code like my updated answer